# Select node/descendant pairs for every permutation in tree hierarchy

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I have a folder tree structure represented in an SQL Server table:

```
Id  ParentId
------------
1   NULL
2   1
3   1
4   2
5   3
```

I would like to build an SQL query to give me **all of the permutations** of Folder Id to Descendant Folder Id:

```
FolderId  DescendantFolderId
----------------------------
1         2
1         3
1         4
1         5
2         4
3         5
```

So far I have written the following query, but it only selects the immediately related node/child pairs:

```
WITH
    RecursiveFolders
AS
(
    SELECT 
        [Id], 
        [ParentId]
    FROM
        [Folders]
    WHERE
        [ParentId] is NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT    
        f.[Id],
        f.[ParentId]
    FROM    
        [Folders] f
        INNER JOIN
            RecursiveFolders r
        ON
            r.Id = f.ParentId
)
SELECT DISTINCT
    [ParentId] as FolderId,
    [Id] as DescendantFolderId
FROM
    RecursiveFolders
WHERE
    [ParentId] is not NULL
ORDER BY
    [ParentId],
    [Id]
```

Outputs:

```
FolderId  DescendantFolderId
----------------------------
1         2
1         3
2         4
3         5
```

How can I select ALL permutations of folder to descendant folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the datatype `hierarchyID` in concert with `IsDescendantOf()` within a `CROSS APPLY`  ... could also be a self `JOIN`

**Example or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=864a23a871028dead240ea0ff9f2b5f1)**

```
;with cte as (
      Select ID
            ,ParentId 
            ,HierID = convert(hierarchyid,concat('/',ID,'/'))
      From   Folders 
      Where  ParentId is null
      Union  All
      Select ID  = r.ID
            ,ParentId  = r.ParentId 
            ,HierID = convert(hierarchyid,concat(p.HierID.ToString(),r.ID,'/'))
      From   Folders r
      Join   cte p on r.ParentId  = p.ID
)
Select FolderID = A.ID
      ,DescendantFolderId = B.ID
 From  cte A
 Cross Apply (
               Select *
                 From cte 
                Where HierID.IsDescendantOf( A.HierID ) = 1
             ) B
 Where A.ID<>B.ID
 Order By A.HierID
```

**Results**

```
FolderID    DescendantFolderId
1           2
1           3
1           5
1           4
2           4
3           5
```

Comment: Thank you John! This is working perfectly!